# how do I use a windows form user control in another project? type errors thrown?

Tags: winforms

I've created a simple user control in Windows Forms that consists of a button and a textbox. The click event of the button resizes the text box and adds some text. I don't know if this part of the code is relevant, but I'll include it anyway.

```
namespace testUserControl
{
    public partial class UserControl1 : UserControl
    {
        public UserControl1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Width = 200;
            textBox1.Height = 200;
            textBox1.Text = "this text was added by the button";
        }
    }
}
```

In the project where I'm trying to include this user control in several places, I have a button with a click event that adds a tab page. I want the tab page to include this custom user control. However, when I use this code, I get an error stating: `'testUserControl is a namespace but used like a type'`:

```
namespace main_project_winform
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            TabPage item = new TabPage("header text");
            tabControlCitations.Controls.Add(item);
            testUserControl u = new testUserControl(); //<!-- error occurs here
            item.Controls.Add(u);
        }
    }
}
```

How do I include and use this custom user control in my project?

Comment: You should name your control.

Comment: .Net public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Comment: Thank you for letting me know. I'll make sure I follow the standards accordingly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the error clearly states, `testUserControl` is a namespace.

The type is `UserControl1`.
You will also need a `using` statement to import the namespace.

Comment: Thank you. It's a simple error, certainly, but I just couldn't figure it out. Too late in the day perhaps. I added `using testUserControl`, renamed my user control to `myUserControl`, and it's working when I use `myUserControl u = new myUserControl();` Thank you again. I'll accept the answer once the time limit expires.